# object_detection - ImportError: cannot import name 'dataset_builder'

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I recently updated to tf 1.5 and while trying to invoke train.py under research/object_detection i hit an error saying

For more info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 50, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
ImportError: cannot import name 'dataset_builder'
```

Is there any circular dependency or is it just me that gets this error? Or on your end everything is working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you notice in the code the dataset_builder is called from object_detection.builders, meaning that you have to execute the code from one directory up (from research directory). In my case, I just moved the train.py code to research directory and then issued it as normal and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem (with Tensorflow 1.7.0), but I solved it by updating my [models/research/object_detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) files, i.e. pulling the latest updates from the [repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models): https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git.

I assume that the pretrained models I used were newer than my local object_detection files.

Comment: Yes we avoided all this hurdles all together by moving to cloud training. So we just prepare the data set, upload it and train it in the cloud.